# Trim first zero after dot twice sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to compare assembly versions using SQL Server, however there can be more than one version returned and I need it be in a six digit format.

For example, the assembly version `2.00.0001` and I need that to be returned as `2.0.1`.

There could be versions like `1.01.0031` that I would need to be `1.1.31`.

This works but is there a better way of doing it?

```
select left(left([output],9),1)+'.'+substring(left([output],9),3,1)+'.'+substring(right(left([output],9),1),1,1)
```

Comment: will the pattern be always fixed with 2 `.`s?

Comment: Yeah, it will always be 1 number, dot, 2 numbers, dot, 4 numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `ParseName` function, you can achieve this. Try this -

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(100) = '01.10.0031'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@val, 3))) + '.' + 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@val, 2))) + '.' + 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@val, 1)))
```

**Result**

```
1.10.31
```

Comment: This is not going to work. What happens if the value is 01.10.0031? If you replace every instance of '0' with an empty string you prevent any value that is divisible by 10.

Comment: @SeanLange: You are right. I have modified my answer. btw thanks for point out.

Answer (score 2):

For limited numbers of zeros, you can replace `.0` with `.`:

```
select replace(replace(replace([output], '.00', '.'), '.0', '.'), '..', '.0.')
```

This is a bit of a hack, but it is relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

Because the pattern would always be fixed, you could use `substring` and `cast` to do this.

```
select substring(col,1,1) + '.'
       cast(cast(substring(col,3,2) as int) as varchar(2)) + '.'
       cast(cast(substring(col,6,4) as int) as varchar(4))
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic solution that will work with any format provided there are no alpha and '.' is the seperator.

```
Create  Function [dbo].[SplitString] ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name VARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @pos INT
 Declare @Return Varchar(MAX) = ''

 WHILE CHARINDEX('.', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX('.', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = Convert(Varchar(MAX), Convert(Int, SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)))

  Set @Return = @Return + @name + '.'

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 RETURN @Return + Convert(Varchar(MAX), Convert(Int, @stringToSplit))
END
```

---

```
Declare @ver Varchar(100) = '7.00.0001'

Select dbo.splitstring(@ver)
```

Comment: As string splitters go the while loop is the worst possible way to do this from a performance standpoint. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work as long as the pattern contains two decimal points and should handle any number of zeros in each position

```
DECLARE @version VARCHAR(19)
SET @version = '2.00.0001'

SELECT 
  CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@version,1,CHARINDEX('.',@version,1)-1) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.'+
  CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@version,CHARINDEX('.',@version,1)+1,CHARINDEX('.',@version,CHARINDEX('.',@version,1) + 1)-CHARINDEX('.',@version,1)-1)  AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.' +
  CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@version,CHARINDEX('.',@version,CHARINDEX('.',@version,1) + 1)+1,LEN(@version)) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5))
```